How To Frame Around Stair Landing
We are looking to renovate our basement, adding in framing and insulation among other improvements to replace our current walls, which are simply a laminate wood panel nailed to some furring strips fixed to the cinder block foundation.
Our question is how to work around our stair landing?
The length of the landing is 5 inches over the width of the stairs which should give us the play room we need to meet "Landing Long as the Stair is Wide" rule after accounting for 3.5" of framing and drywall.
The "lazy" way would be to pull the landing flooring, treads, and riser and build in the frame. Then cut material down to size and reinstall. Is this acceptable practice or are we better off tearing out the landing and final steps and rebuilding from scratch here?


Code states the stairs can be no less than 36" in width. If it is a house built before 1954, it may be able to be grandfathered in, where being smaller than that would be ok, but I think that would be, only if it already is too narrow, not making it narrower (not code) if it was already a code approved width.

Our house is built in 1973, our stairs leading from the first floor landing are the minimum 36" meeting modern requirements. Our landing has a width to match that of the stairs plus the beams, measuring about 45" (including the nose, perhaps closer to 44"). Our landing has a length (wall to riser) of roughly 41" which should give us room to still meet a 36" length on the landing after adding frame and drywall.

Do you have anything against a standard stair skirt?

I do not - if you are asking why there isn't one, this was done by the prior homeowner.
